# How to insert the start datetime and enddate time in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to insert startdatetime and end date time time.

table availability

| id | userid | startdatetime | enddatetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-01-27 10:00:00 | 2023-01-27 12:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-01-28 10:00:00 | 2023-01-28 12:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-01-29 10:00:00 | 2023-01-29 12:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-01-30 10:00:00 | 2023-01-30 12:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-01-31 10:00:00 | 2023-01-31 12:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-02-01 10:00:00 | 2023-02-01 12:00:00 |

Continuing on till 2023-02-25 12:00:00.

The start date time will be 2023-01-27 10:00:00   and end date time 2023-02-25 12:00:00.

```
for($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i->modify('+1 day'))
        {

            
            $_attribute = array(

                'start_date_time' => $i->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

                'end_date_time'   => $i->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

                'user_id'         => $user->id

            );

           \App\models\availability::create($_attribute);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CarbonPeriod instead of for loop

```
$begin = Carbon::parse('2023-01-27');
$end = Carbon::parse('2023-03-25');

$dates = CarbonPeriod::create($being, $end)->toArray();

$now = now(); // needed for created_at and updated_at

$attributes = [];

foreach ($dates as $date) {
  $attributes[] = [
    'start_date_time' => $date->hour(10)->minute(0)->seconds(0),
    'end_date_time' => $date->hour(12)->minute(0)->seconds(0),
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    // must add these because we are using insert()
    'created_at' => $now,
    'updated_at' => $now,
  ];
}

\App\models\availability::insert($attributes);
```

Comment: you can remove created_at and updated_at if you do not need them